# STACK_MESSAGE error thrown by NetSuite

Tags: rest, netsuite

Recently I've been getting an Error from NetSuite. We have a Custom Restlet which is receiving a JSON which is used to create Sales Order inside of NetSuite. In SandBox it worked fine so far, but in production not.

```
Error:
STACK_MESSAGE: java.lang.IllegalStateException: wrap should never be called unless shutter.visibleToScripts is called first.class com.netledger.app.common.scripting.nlobjError/class java.lang.Class
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetSuite has this cute little thing where it throws Java exceptions when running JS. My presumption is that the JS is compiled as Java before being run, so sometimes you can get unhandelable execptions like this one (or having fixed sized arrays in JS.. crazy right!).

IllegalStateException
Signals that a **method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time.**
*http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html*

What you can do is try doing some unit testing to find out what part of your code is causing the bug, then try to find a workaround as if it were Java code.